# Fastest python algorithm to divide a list of numbers into N groups that maximizes the total mean differences of every two closest groups

Tags: python, algorithm, grouping, cluster-analysis, greatest-n-per-group

Say I have a list of integers

```
[1, 107, 1010, 3, 121, 5, 1024, 118, 101, 1, 123, 1357]
```

I want to divide them into N=3 groups (not necessarily equal in length), meanwhile maximize the total differences between the mean values of every two closest groups. This is an extreme example, the expected partition is obviously

```
res = [[1, 3, 5, 1],
       [107, 121, 118, 101, 123],
       [1010, 1024, 1357]]
```

I use the following function to calculate the total differences between the mean values of every two closest groups

```
import numpy as np

def calc_mean_diff_sum(list_of_lists):
    list_of_lists.sort(key=lambda x: np.mean(x))
    return np.sum([np.mean(list_of_lists[i+1]) - np.mean(group)
                   for i, group in enumerate(list_of_lists[:-1])])

print(calc_mean_diff_sum(res))
>>> 1127.8333333333333
```

However, how should I divide a list of 12 random numbers into 3 groups?

```
a = np.random.rand(12,)
```

Right now I am using brute force enumeration of all possible partitionings and choose the one that maximizes the `calc_mean_diff_sum` function, but I think there must be some faster algorithms out there. Any suggestions?

I want to say this question has further implication of a clustering problem based on similarities.

Comment: Isn't the difference between mean values maximal if you put only minimum in 1st, only maximum in 2nd, and the rest in the 3rd group?

Comment: Is N predefined in the problem or your program is supposed to come up with the value of N first and then give the groups later, as well?

Comment: For my problem N is predefined, but if N is undefined that would also be an interesting problem.

Comment: @zvone Not necessarily for example: `[1,2,3,40,50,51]`best partitioning is `[1,2,3],[40],[50,51]`

Comment: If N is fixed then it sounds like this is a k-means clustering problem (to me) but only in one dimension. Google the algorithm and try to adapt and implement. If still stuck then you can always ask for help here.

Comment: @willcrack the differences between mean values of `[1,2,3],[40],[50,51]` are `38 + 10.5 = 48.5`. The differences between mean values of `[1],[2,3,40,50],[51]` are `22.75 + 27.25 = 50`, so I don't get your point. In fact, regardless of the number of groups, the total is always `biggest_mean - smallest_mean` which is always optimal if the extremes are single values in two groups.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not clear what the question is. As it is currently formulated, the stated expected result is wrong and the correct result is always trivial.

Comment: @ShaunHan dividing into `[1], [107, 1010, 3, 121, 5, 1024, 118, 101, 1, 123], [1357]` results in a greater difference: `1356`.

Comment: @zvone you'r right! I misinterpreted the question

Comment: As zvone points out, the objective needs debugging, but let me suggest that 1) the k-means objective might be what you want 2) there exists an efficient dynamic program to optimize it in 1D: https://www.dannyadam.com/blog/2019/07/kmeans1d-globally-optimal-efficient-1d-k-means/